# difference between `...` and $(...) in bash

Tags: bash

Consider the following two scripts:

```
a=`ls -l`
a=$(ls -l)
```

This is a common use case for me, and I basically use both options interchangeably. Is there any difference? In which use case would you use one or another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backquote (**`**) is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g.

```
foo=`command`
```

The

```
foo=$(command)
```

syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082